# Why is my page taller than the <html> element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser, height

I am aghast. In Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox, this page is really tall! I've been using jQuery to set the height of an element to be almost as tall as the  element. It looks perfect in Chrome, but IE and FF render a really tall page. What's even weirder is, when using Firefox's inspector, I can see the page extends far beyond the height of the  element!

The jQuery:

```
(function($){
   var resize = function(){
      var height = $('html').height();
      $('#wrap > div').height(height-38);
      $('html').height(height); // Added this to try and fix the height
   };
   $(window).resize(resize).load(resize);
})(jQuery);
```

The HTML layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <!-- ... --->
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrap"><div> <!-- I want the child of #wrap to be the height of the entire page. -->
         <div id="left"><div>
            <!-- ... -->
         </div></div>
         <div id="main">
            <!-- ... -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="body">
               <!-- ... -->
            </div>
         </div>
      </div></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
html{height: 100%;}
body{background: url('images/body.jpg') no-repeat fixed left top; border: 8px solid #BBB0A2; border-width: 8px 0 0 6px; min-width: 902px;}
#wrap{max-width: 1130px;}
#wrap > div{float: right;}
#main{float: left; width: 630px; height: 100%; padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px; background: #FFFFFF;}
#body{margin-top: 20px; font: 13px/18px Georgia, serif; color: #AE9073; position: relative;}
```

Here's the web site I'm trying to work with: http://www.phoenixarizonashutters.com/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it because you have padding?  I'm not a web developer but doesn't the fact that main takes up 100% of the container + padding make it bigger than the container?

Comment: you have 20px left and right and 10px top and 20px bottom padding ...

Comment: Not sure what this means -> _"to set the height of an element to be almost as tall as the element."_

Comment: I took your code out of the function and it worked fine on my ipad in safari and chrome.  Here is a js fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/3bSgN/.  I don't have access to ie so give it a try.

Comment: You're missing **height:100%** from the body tag. Both <html> and <body> need to contain this if you wish to use all available retail space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your included code doesn't demonstrate the problem, but if I visit your site, I can see these two elements:

```
<div style="height: 695px;">...</div>
<div class="clear" style="height: 695px;"></div>
```

Your clearing div probably doesn't need a height - remove whatever is causing that and your site becomes more reasonably sized.

Comment: I actually discovered this a few hours after posting the question. Thank you for noticing! I gave the inner wrapping element an ID instead to clear this up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood your request, but your code has a lot of inline styles, which is a bad practice.

You have a div.clear that is being affected by your jQuery function

```
$('#wrap > div').height(height-38)
```

To prevent your selector from selecting .clear you can use the :not method.

```
jQuery $('#wrap > div:not(".clear")').height(height-38)
```